# Is it possible to make a Windows program's browse dialogue (not just explorer windows), default to quick access shortcuts?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, default-settings, windows-10-quick-access

In windows, there's a folder option that lets you change the default behavior of the left pane, to default to either "This PC" or "Quick Access".

The problem I have is, this doesn't apply to open or save dialogues, where I do 90% of my folder navigation. So what happens is, when I open or save, I always get jumped to the C: drive (or wherever) at the bottom of the list, and have to scroll up to quick access. Doing this 100 times a day gets old.

So is there a registry trick that might let me change the default behavior... if not globally, then at least for a specific app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the Windows *Open-Save* dialog is a file used in common by almost all applications, *each application* maintains it's own Most Recently Used (MRU) and default folder location.

[IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/), for example, has persistent settings for the default folder location.

[image: IrfanView Default Folder Location]

However, if you use another application, e.g., Notepad, that does *not* have such a setting, then it defaults to the Windows "root".

Comment: Ah, thanks... using a registry monitor, I found that at some point photoshop accesses a small file in the windows "AutomaticDestination" windows folder, found at  
%appdata%\microsoft\windows\recent\automaticdestinations  

When I look at this file in text editor, I see my recent files. sounds like it's defaulting to windows MRU, not an adobe-made MRU. If I were smarter and motivated I could try making a script that would somehow replace that small file, with one that points to quick launch. But probably I would just break something.